# How do i correctly search and replace for strings in a HTML-Document with javascript and DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's say i have a line in a HTML-File looking like this:

```
this is <br>a <b>test</b>
```

I want to find this string (the complete line) by using javascript and for example put:

```
<font color="..."></font> around it.
```

around it.

Actually i'm iterating over all text nodes in the DOM structure, but the text is splitted in these nodes, so i think this is the wrong way.

If i iterate over the element nodes i can use textContent perfectly for searching, but not for replacing/changing because the HTML-tags are completely missing.

So what's the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: I doubt you want to put a `<font>` tag around something in 2014.

Comment: You should avoid putting style properties in HTML, as they are becoming deprecated in favor of external CSS. HTML markup should instead be reserved for content.

Comment: well my question is not about the tags that i want to wrap around, it's more about how to solve this problem in the DOM structure.<font> was meant as an example, it could be <div ...>, <b> or something else instead.

Comment: @TylerH Sometimes you need inline CSS, Mathletics was talking about not using a deprecated `font` tag..

Comment: See this page http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: i understood what TylerH wanted to say, but again, the <font> tag was an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve your goal by doing some RegExp on the parent node.

If your not familiarized with RegExp, here some nice reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

```
var text = "<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul><br>bla bla this is <br>a <b>test</b> <br>";
var result = text.match(/(this.*<\/b>)/i);
console.log(result);
```

In action:

http://jsfiddle.net/G2e5k/

Comment: i thought about using regular expressions, but i don't know which tags are inside the HTML. What i want to do is a search function with highlighting like firefox does, just for learning purposes.

Comment: I think RegExp could really help you here. Take a look at the changes I make on the answer.

Comment: You don't want to run a Regex and update the HTML if you have any handlers in there. It's safer to modify the DOM/

Comment: @Renato Galvão: but how do i hightlight a word like "test" which is kind of garbled to "t<br>e<br>s<br>t" in HTML?